# Parse XML string using SAX

Tags: xml, android, string, sax

Is there any way to parse an XML string using Android SAX?

Comment: On the other hand you could just use the Simple library instead which is a million times better than SAX: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, first define a SAX [ContentHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html):

```
class MyXmlContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {
   ... // implement SAX callbacks here
}
```

then you can use the [Xml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html) utility class:

```
Xml.parse(xmlString, new MyXmlContentHandler());
```