# xml parsing in android

Tags: android

i am new to android. I want example how to parse xml file in android.could anybody provide me a program

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Parse XML string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850412/android-parse-xml-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are plenty of examples out there, here is an example [CLICK](http://d-codepages.com/index.php/android/coding-advanced/24-xml-parsing-using-xmlpullparser-loading-images-using-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following tutorial:
[XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html)