# xml parsing in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xml parsing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984530/xml-parsing-in-android)

i am new to android . hows can i do parsing of the url http://simplyappointments.com/businessinfoxml.php?email=sujit_jitu06@rediffmail.com
can anyone help me in doing parsing.
I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAX parser. See an example [here](http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html).