# parsing in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xml parsing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984530/xml-parsing-in-android)

i have to parse  the below give file in xml format
 
 
-

The url for above file is http://simplyappointments.com/businessinfoxml.php?email=sujit_jitu06@rediffmail.com

Can anybody help me in this.... I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: your link has "body { position:relative; top:0px; margin-top: 33px; }", is this the xml file you are referring ?

Comment: -1 I just realized the same question was posted twice by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the normal Java DOM stuff.

For instance to retrieve the value of the *Transaction* attribute from the given link:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                   .newDocumentBuilder();
String urlStr = "http://simplyappointments.com/businessinfoxml.php"+
                   "?email=sujit_jitu06@rediffmail.com";

InputStream inputStream = new URL(urlStr).openStream();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);
Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("businessinfo").item(0);
return element.getAttribute("Transaction");
```

If you must retrieve an XML document through the network make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your Android manifest.